# Search Salesforce with selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, salesforce

I am trying to use selinum for chrome with Salesforce to search the salesforce for case number. 
I am able to login and write the case number in the salesforce search box, but I am not able to retrieve the output.

My code:

```
# create a new Chrome session
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver_path)
driver.implicitly_wait(300)
driver.maximize_window()

# Navigate to the application home page
driver.get("https://salesforce.com/xxx")
driver.implicitly_wait(100)
search_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@title='Search Salesforce']")
search_field.click();
search_field.clear();
search_field.send_keys("case number").wait();
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@title='case number']");
search_field.click();
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
search_field.submit();
search_field.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I am not able to make comments due to lack of reputation points, this is what I wanted to add to @RockinWatson's [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60607281/7578937) above:

There is a chance that the 'value' attribute does not get updated after you enter value in search field. In that case, either

1. click somewhere outside of the box
2. or hit tab using `search_field.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);`
3. or hit enter using `search_field.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);` as long as it doesn't take you away from the page.

Comment: nothing change using tab or return. 
what I want to do is hitting search and getting results, but so far I just have the value written to the search box and that's it.

Comment: Ah gotcha. The question was not clear. It sounded as if you wanted to retrieve the value from the search box itself. If you want to capture the results, you would need to give us details about the search result page. Usually the search results have a common property (for eg each of them may have the same class). Check out [find_elements](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html) to get them in a list.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to get the value Attribute from the element after entering the text.

```
input_text = search_field.get_attribute("value")
```

Comment: It gives input_text of no type?